# Content type that are supported by Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, mime-types

I need to map various video and audio file types that can be upload to my application.
In the following [microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) they publish the supported mime types by IE.

but I think that this list is very partial. For example I couldn't find there the content type '**video/quicktime**' that is also generated by my IE8
So my first question is - where can I find a list of all IE/windows supported mime types.

My second question is - is there a difference between the mime-type and the content-type.
because for example in [this file type list](http://www.filesuffix.com/?m=search&e=avi)  the mime type of .AVI file is **video/x-msvideo** while the checked content type of it is **video/avi**
So why there is a difference between mime and content type?

Comment: Hmmmm. What are you using on the server end? Would it not be feasible to detection on server side instead, either using MIME magic or a library like [GetID3 (for PHP)](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: I can't change existing design that is based on detecting by the browser. I just need to extend it to support new mime types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer can support an effectively infinite list of MIME types depending on what applications are installed on the client. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/07/01/ie-and-the-accept-header.aspx for an explanation of the ACCEPT header and information about changes that have been made for IE9.

MIME Type and Content-Type are often used interchangeably. The Content-Type header contains a MIME Type and [optionally] character set information. In the case of AVI, there are a number of different MIME types which are all the same thing under the covers; that happens quite often (e.g. there are about 8 supported MIME types for JavaScript).